# Not able to see the error logs in Docker logs [Using cmd "Docker logs <Container_id>"]

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, servlets, docker-logs

```
1.AmazonSNSclient snsClient=null;
2.snsClient=AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard.withRegion("us-east-2").build();
3.System.out.println(snsClient);
4.snsClient.publish(topicAr,"Sample SNS Message");
5.System.out.println("Success in sending the request to SNS");
```

The above code is part of java servlet deployed using docker container that uses tomcat as server. Till line[3] everything is fine and I can see the logs but due to some issue at line[4] compiler is not going beyond line [3] and I am not able to see any error message in docker logs.